# Mongodb: offset() is collection specific or query specific?

Tags: mongodb, morphia

When is have a code like this in my morphia code

> query.offset((pageNo - 1) * pageSize);

does it skip the number of "only" matching rows to the query or the first **(pageNo - 1)*pageSize** rows of the collection? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Morphia's `offset` is the same as Mongo's `skip`; in either case you're specifying how many rows in the query results to skip over before returning result rows.  So in the terms of your question, `offset()` is query specific.